# Patient's data anonymisation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, biostatistics, medicine

Is there any available statistical method for assessing whether anonymisation performed on patient data in a medical dataset is sufficient?

Comment: Sufficient for what purpose?

Comment: For the anonymization. Is there a statistical method that tells you when you have anonymized the data enough so that the patients cannot be identified.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one-size-fits-all method. Proper anonymization, or de-identification, invariably  requires both training and thought. You’ll find essentially this answer if you read regulations such as the US HIPAA (Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act) that govern confidentiality of patient data.

Comment: I was thinking of using information theory. Like if the information conveyed from the data about the patient identity is less or equal to that after one scrambles the data, then we should be able to conclude that the patient cannot be identified. But it is just an idea right now.